# Not able to start OBIEE 12c Server components

Tags: obiee

I have tried to install OBIEE 12c in windows 2012 R2 and Successfully installed.But I am not able to start all the BI components.I have tried through Em as well as through the command (start.cmd).But no luck.Only obijh1 is in running state.rather than that all the components are in SHUTDOWN state.Please check the screen shot.I am stuck here for last 2 days.Any Idea will be helpfull.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the Windows service created in installation time.

You have the logs of the windows services in `DOMAIN_HOME/bilogs/windowsservices.log`